# Codeigniter flash message from file to file

Tags: php, codeigniter

can anyone explain me how to forward a notification from one php file to other?
For example, i have one file InvoiceGenerator.php where i have function for generating some invoices, and i have automatic message in this file as $response. In every case from file InvoiceGenerator.php redirect to InvoiceRequests.php where is updated information of that invoice.
Sample redirect from InvoiceGenerator.php

```
redirect('/invoiceRequests', 'location');
```

And there is $response, message that i have if i comment that redirect. How to show that $response in InvoiceRequests.php?

Answer (score 0):

You can save the $response to a session and you can call it anytime as long as you don't clear the session.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['id'] = $response;
```

Comment: Do i have to make one more .php file to include it in InvoiceRequests.php? File who will forward this message?

Comment: you can put it in the same php file but I prefer making another php file to save the value to the session and redirect it to the desired page.

Answer (score 0):

Using flashdata, in your controller, before redirecting:

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('my_response', $response);
```

In invoiceRequests view you can retrieve it like this

```
echo $this->session->flashdata('my_response');
```

Comment: Thank's that is most easy way :)

Comment: Would you please flag this as the correct response so that next users can find it easily?